# Consuming and reading web service that returns DataSet XML in C# MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please I have this complex web service to consume which is returning DataSet XML. Please how do I consume this to extract the data: The most needed part are code, value, description  which are all between tags `<response>..</response>` as indicated below;

The data actually needed are `<response> -----code="311" value="FAILED" description="Authentication request failed due to Digipass token issues" /> --------</response>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="response">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="user" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
<xs:element name="status" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
<xs:element name="error" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="message" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="operation" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="timestamp" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element ref="response" /> 
  </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<response diffgr:id="response1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" operation="AUTHENTICATION" timestamp="2015-11-11 07:45:43.339" msdata:hiddenresponse_Id="0">
  <user diffgr:id="user1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" id="mlawal" msdata:hiddenresponse_Id="0" /> 
  <status diffgr:id="status1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" code="311" value="FAILED" description="Authentication request failed due to Digipass token issues" msdata:hiddenresponse_Id="0" /> 
  <error diffgr:id="error1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted" code="1" message="Validation Failed" msdata:hiddenresponse_Id="0" /> 
  </response>
  </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
  </DataSet>
```

Comment: have you checked the `MSDN Documentation on the following`
[Loading a DataSet from XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes I have but didn't get any headway with their documentation

Comment: are you familiar with the DataTable.LoadFromXML since you are using a `DataSet` you can get to the DataTable by DataSet.Tables[0] etc... do you have C# code that you are actually using to call the web service..? google `C# Stackoverflow DataTable.LoadFromXML` tons of working examples

Comment: I really don't have any clue or just coming across this complex dataSet xml. I need help absolutely. I have google the topic you sent me but still looking at the long list of search results to see which one is applicable to my case if any...thanks in advance @MethodMan